# Trivial fibration over $S^1$ and closed 1-form

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

Tischler's theorem says that a closed differentiable manifold $M$ has a nondegenerate real closed 1-form if and only if $M$ is a fiber bundle over the circle $S^1$.

Except for the condition "nondegeneracy", what more condition should one put on a closed 1-form $\theta$ to guarantee that $\theta$ gives the trivial fiber bundle over $S^1$?

Comment: I suppose the obvious answer is that the form is the derivative of a function $M \to S^1$, which allows the definition of the fiber.  There has to be a vector field dual to the 1-form so that the "return map" from going around the $S^1$ factor is isotopic to the identity map.

Comment: @RyanBudney  Thank you for the comment.   Is there a condition on the form without referring to the map to $S^1$ for the above question? I would expect there is a (co)homological condition working.

Comment: The condition given by @RyanBudney is necessary and sufficient, and can be expressed in other language by saying that return map represents the identity element of the mapping class group of the fiber. Given the complexity of mapping class groups in many known cases, e.g. when $M$ has dimension 3 and the fiber has dimension 2, I would not expect there to be a simple cohomological interpretation.